# The webOnlyAssetManager getter is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use `assetManager` from `dart:ui_web` instead

Tags: flutter, toast

The webOnlyAssetManager getter is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use `assetManager` from
`dart:ui_web` instead.

`Fluttertoast.showToast( msg: 'Success', toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER, backgroundColor: Colors.green, textColor: Colors.white, fontSize: 16.0, );`

I am getting a warning: The webOnlyAssetManager getter is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use `assetManager` from `dart:ui_web` instead

Answer (score 1):

To fix this problem you may change `flutter toast_web.dart` inside your project (Your Project/External Library/Dart Packages).

Include:

```
import 'dart:ui_web'
```

And change:

From

```
ui.webOnlyAssetManager.getAssetUrl('...')
```

To

```
Uri.encodeFull('...')
```

But, this will be reset to original code if you update the Flutter.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem has to do with the package ([`flutterToast`](https://pub.dev/packages/fluttertoast) ) that you're using.

If you [inspect the source code](https://github.com/ponnamkarthik/FlutterToast/blob/fc431199670788c308b90013b662388159178cef/lib/fluttertoast_web.dart#L85). You'll see that they're using `webOnlyAssetManager`:

[image]

```dart
 final jsUrl = ui.webOnlyAssetManager.getAssetUrl(
      'packages/fluttertoast/assets/toastify.js',
    );
```

which is deprecated. You'll have to wait for the package maintainer to release a new version.